# How to prevent function/event from firing multiple times

Tags: javascript

There is an issue with the `createResetHandler` function.

The `createResetHandler` function event fires multiple times.

Seen Here: https://jsfiddle.net/oxjzmk18/

To reproduce, when the exit button appears on the screen, click it multiple times.

Clicking on the exit button multiple times causes the event to be fired multiple times.

You have to mouse click the exit button more than 1 time.

How do I prevent that, so that it only fires 1 time?

How is that fixed in the code?

```
  function createResetHandler(player) {
    const resetVideo = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    resetVideo.forEach(function resetVideoHandler(video) {
      video.addEventListener("click", function resetVideoHandler() {
        player.destroy();
        console.log("createResetHandler");
      });
    })
  }
```

[image]

Comment: The way this code is written, after the clicking event is launched, the RESULT of the function will be referenced, not the actual function itself. Is this intentional or not?

Comment: That's just the way I did it, I fix that.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oxjzmk18/ I put createResetHandler in console log instead. I just put a name in there, has no significance though. Just to show that it fires multiple times when the exit button is clicked.

Comment: I clicked on the reset button in your link and it showed "remove player" in the console only once

Comment: possibly it occurs only on a specific player, not on all of them. Hope this helps you getting started!

Comment: Mouse click multiple times, not 1 time on the exit button.

Comment: You are incorrect, you have to mouse click the exit button more than 1 time.

Comment: attach `exitClickHandler` to exit button when a player is opened, and attach with options `{once:  true}`

Comment: I simulated a couple of things. I get a 'removePlayer' message for each player that is currently active. May have to do with the foreach loop you use. EDIT: I see that I misread your question a little. Hope this information is helpful nonetheless

Comment: an ugly way to do it (although it would probably work) would be to create a boolean isResetting = false. Then check if the boolean is set to false before you execute your logic. After the logic is executed, set the boolean to true. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work.

Attach event handler to the active exit button only, `document.querySelector` could be better choice in this case.

```
const resetVideo = document.querySelectorAll(".container.active .exit");
```

attach event with `once: true`, so event handler is removed once the event is fired.

```
  function createResetHandler(player) {

    const resetVideo = document.querySelectorAll(".container.active .exit");
    resetVideo.forEach(function resetVideoHandler(video) {
      video.addEventListener("click", function resetVideoHandler() {
        player.destroy();
        console.log("removePlayer");
      }, {
        once: true
      });
    })
  }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

- once

> A boolean value indicating that the listener should be invoked at most
> once after being added. If true, the listener would be automatically
> removed when invoked.

Or using `removeEventListener`

```
  function createResetHandler(player) {

    const resetVideo = document.querySelectorAll(".container.active .exit");
    resetVideo.forEach(function resetVideoHandler(video) {
      const resetVideoHandler = () => {
         video.removeEventListener("click", resetVideoHandler);
          player.destroy();
          console.log("removePlayer");
      };
      video.addEventListener("click", resetVideoHandler);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Can you show how it would be written using removeEventListener also?